# How to start/launch the third party application installed in Windows Phone 7 from redirect URL (HTTP)

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to start/launch my third party windows phone 7 application and pass some parameter to  the application like activation code etc.

note : Assuming application is already downloaded from Windows market Place and installed in device.

I have thought of using SMS message interceptor windows api, but it seems that this is not 
supported in present in Windows Phone 7 release.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with the current SDK.

Comment: Thanks Matt,is there any way we can achive this..anu Idea.

Comment: @Sundeep No. There is no work around for this., but I'd expect this to change in a future update. The ability to do it is there under the hood, just not publicly available.